# Dead locks when using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType managed object context on two threads

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, concurrency, deadlock

I'm using an `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` `NSManagedObjectContext` and a deadlock happens in the following situation.

On a background thread, a call to performBlock: is made. That block contains a `executeFetchRequest:error:` call.

While that block is executing, the main thread makes a call to `performBlockAndWait:`. The main thread waits while the block of the background thread finishes. That's normal.

When the `executeFetchRequest:error:` call is made on the background's thread block, a dead lock happens.

I imagine that the `executeFetchRequest:error:` is waiting for the main thread for the `performBlockAndWait:` to finishes.

Is that a bug? Or I don't understand something? To me, all this code seems valid with the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` MOCs.

Comment: This does not happens a lot, but when it happens, well… the app is dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType does not automagically make NSManagedObjectContext thread-safe. If you need to use Core Data on multiple threads, you should still use separate contexts for each thread.

Comment: What's the point of the private queue then? From the documentation : "Instead of you creating and managing a thread or queue with which a context is associated, here the context owns the queue and manages all the details for you (provided that you use the block-based methods as described below)." Seems to me that I should use block-based method and use only one context.

Comment: The way I've understood NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType is that it lets you carry out blocks of operations on private threads, but you still need to manually avoid race conditions arising from accessing it from multiple threads. After reading the documentation again, I'm not 100% sure...

Comment: I've make sure that we use a NSMainQueueConcurrencyType when we performBlockAndWait: on the main thread. Works for now.